# Is it possible to bundle something like ffmpeg into a node app?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Currently, I'm using node to create a script to ensure that files meet our standards and one requirement is to ensure that audio files don't exceed a maximum loudness. For this I'm using `ffmpeg` and `child_proccesses` exec function. The problem though would be that this would require every user to install and configure `ffmpeg` on their machines. Is there any way to bundle `ffmpeg` with the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg-cli module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-cli) claims to do precisely this. From the documentation, it "will download and extract necessary binaries for your OS!".

Answer (score 1):

Hans's suggestion was fantastic, and may be helpful to others, but I found this one which better suited my problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static

It simply downloads the proper binary on `npm install` and gives you the path to it.